# Adding new column, based on values of another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Can anyone help, i'm new to Python so bear with me.

My data looks like this but has all the region information available. I'm trying to create a new column 'actual price' that works out the price based on the region. as for every entry I have each price for every region. is this possible.

```
data = [[1, 'EDF', 'Eastern', 400, 500, 300], [2, 'EDF', 'Southern', 200, 100, 300], [3, 'NPower', 
        'Eastern', 600, 500, 700]] 


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Supplier', 'Region', 'Av Price', 'Eastern Price',  
'Southern Price']) 

df
```

Comment: What is your expected output for the sample data?

Comment: sorry that would have been helpful so

    ID   Supplier   Region   Av Price   Eastern Price   Southern Price  Price
    1     EDF         Eastern  400          500                   300                   500
    2     EDF         Southern 200         100                   300                   300

THe idea is to get rid of all the regional prices and just have the actual price if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do `df.lookup` here after adding " Price" to the values of the Region column to match the column names of the Price by region:

```
m = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.endswith("Price")]
df['actual_Price'] = m.lookup(df.index,df['Region'].add(" Price"))
```

---

```
print(df)
   ID Supplier    Region  Av Price  Eastern Price  Southern Price  \
0   1      EDF   Eastern       400            500             300   
1   2      EDF  Southern       200            100             300   
2   3   NPower   Eastern       600            500             700   

   actual_Price  
0           500  
1           300  
2           500
```

Comment: It appears this has worked but I have a warning

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Comment: @LMR is your dataframe a reference of any other dataframe or is it the first/source dataframe?

Comment: it was created from taking columns from 2 other dataframes if that makes sense?

Comment: @LMR guess there is some issue there. use `.copy()` when referencing the other dataframes, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Thank you @anky that has solved the problem, you have probably jsut saved me a pile of time trying to work it out

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
df["actual_price"] = np.where(df.Region == "Eastern", df["Eastern Price"], df["Southern Price"])
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
conditions = [df['Region'].eq(reg) for reg in df['Region'].unique()]
choices = [df[f'{reg} Price'] for reg in df['Region'].unique()]
df['actual_price'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
   ID Supplier    Region  Av Price  Eastern Price  Southern Price  actual_price
0   1      EDF   Eastern       400            500             300           500
1   2      EDF  Southern       200            100             300           300
2   3   NPower   Eastern       600            500             700           500
```